# RegEx for Phone number +0 (000) 000-00-00

Tags: regex

I have to validate a contact form sent from my site.
Contact number is set as follows :

```
+0 (000) 000-00-00
```

Which RegEx i should use for this form validation?

This one is not correct: `var phoneReg = /^\+\d\\(\d{3}\))\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/`

Thank You

Comment: `/^\+\d \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/`: escape `+`, parentheses, and add spaces where they are expected in the string. See https://regex101.com/r/vf60Vp/1

Comment: Thank you a lot @WiktorStribiżew. It works!